# Counting in Strings of an Array, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

//Solved

I have an array with strings.
I need to count how many letters from every letter in the array are.

My function:

```
...
    for (var k=0; k<=arrB.length; k++) { //Index of the array
        for(var t=0; t<arrB.length; t++) {
            if(p==arrB[k[t]]){ 
    count++;
    }}
    }numb.push(count);
    }
    var inNumber;
    for(var q=0; q< numb.length; q++) {
    if(numb[q]>0) {
        var letterR=q+65; //Number in letter 
        inNumber=String.fromCharCode(letteR);
    showResult(inNumber);
    showResult(numb[q]);
    ...
```

Why is my counter always 0?
Ill be thankful for every little help and advice. Thanks!

Comment: So what *exactly* is the question? You syntax error is probably because your `for` loop right before that `if` has a regular bracket `(` instead of a curly bracket `{`.

Comment: For what it's worth, JS has actual bools. So instead of having `isFalse = 0` (which is a weird name for a variable but whatever) you can actually use `isFalse = false` and later do `isFalse = true`.

Comment: (OP's approach in an entirely de-formatted comment to Matt Burland's answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting letters in an array of strings should be pretty straight forward. For example, you could do this:

```js
var arr=["ABC","CAG","ZXZ"];

var letterCount = arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    for (var i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (p[c[i]]) {
            p[c[i]]++;
        }
        else {
            p[c[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return p;
},{});
```

Which will give you an object `letterCount` that looks like this:

```
{
    "A": 2,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2,
    "G": 1,
    "Z": 2,
    "X": 1
}
```

What you are doing is iterating through the array and for each string iterating through the string. For each letter you check an object (`p`) which is keyed off the letter. If the letter doesn't already exist in the object, you add it and set it's value to `1`. If it does exist, you just increment it by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only one question, dont I have to compare this p[c[i]] with something?

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva: No. `undefined` is considered *falsy*.

Comment: And why do you put this? ,{})

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva: It's an empty object that serves as the seed for the `reduce` function.

Comment: I made it, thanks to everybody!                                                                function countLetters(arr) {
var numb = new Array();
var p;
for (var n=65; n<= 90; n++) {   var count=0;
 p=String.fromCharCode(n);
for (var k=0; k<arr.length; k++) { 
 var a=0;
 for(var t=1; t<=arr.length; t++) {                                                         if(p==arr[k].slice(a,t)){ count++;}a++;
  }}numb.push(count);
}
var inNumber;
for(var q=0; q< numb.length; q++) {
if(numb[q]>0) {
 var letteR=q+65;
    inNumber=String.fromCharCode(letteR);
showResult(inNumber);
showResult(numb[q]);
}}

Answer (score 1):

Split each string into an array of letters counting each occurrence along the way.

```
function countLetters(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (counts, str){
        str.split('').forEach(function (letter) {
            counts[letter] ? counts[letter]++ : counts[letter] = 1;
        });
        return counts;
    }, {});
};

// Example

var arr = ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE'];
console.log(countLetters(arr));
// Logs: Object {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 2, E: 1}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the counting is more specialised than that. Note the expected result for Z.

Comment: I think that is a typo. He initially says `I have an array with 10 strings, every string is with 10 letters. I need to count how many letters from every letter in the array are.`

Comment: Wouldn't bet on it. How many groups the letter appears in would also be a valid counting.

Comment: @deceze: If that's the case then the OP needs to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in you example you have an object `{}` not an array - please fix that. Solution

```
var arr = ["ABC", "CAG", "ZXZ"];

var result = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    var letter = item.charAt(i);

    if (!result[letter]) {
      result[letter] = 0;
    }              

    result[letter] += 1;
  }

});
```

Comment: Technically they don't have an object either. It's just invalid syntax.